# How to rotate a gameobject around another based on the gamepad's right stick position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I have a local coop game where one player plays with a controller and the other with a keyboard. I want the players have a drone that rotates around the ship in 360 degrees based on mouse position. Basically it always points at the mouse. However I want to do the same with the right stick of the controller. The code below works for the mouse but not for the controller.

Edit: I'm using the new Input System.

```
        if (gameObject.name == "Player")
        {
            mousePos = Mouse.current.position.ReadValue();
            mousePos.z = cam.nearClipPlane;
            Vector3 worldpos = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);
            //Debug.Log(mousePos);
            Vector3 aimDirection = (worldpos - transform.position).normalized;
            float angle = Mathf.Atan2(aimDirection.y, aimDirection.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
            aim.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, angle);
            //Debug.Log(angle);
        }
        else
        {
            controllerPos = controllerRightStick.ReadValue<Vector2>();
            controllerPos.z = cam.nearClipPlane;
            Vector3 worldpos = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(controllerPos);
            Vector3 aimDirection = (worldpos - transform.position).normalized;
            float angle = Mathf.Atan2(aimDirection.y, aimDirection.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
            aim.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, angle);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have two codes. one for controller and one for mouse. n your Input Asset define an action which has the action type of `value` and control type of `Vector2`.

[image: Action Properties]

Then add two bindings one having the type of `Delta [Mouse]` and the other of type `Right Stick [Gamepad]`.

[image]
[image]

then write the following callback and assign it in the `Player Input` (`Player Input`'s `Behaviour` should be of type `Invoke Unity Events`):

```
    public void ReadInput(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        var input = context.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        // reset of the code you've written above but it works for mouse and controller
    }
```